# SonarQube blocker: Using "tm" in function declaration

Tags: c++, sonarqube

Using either of the following function declarations in my header file

`time_t MyFunction (tm* time);`

`time_t MyFunction (struct tm* time);`

I'm getting the following Sonar blocker issue:

> Change the reserved name "tm" to a non-reserved one.

I've attempted including `<time.h>` in the header, but this isn't doing the trick. Oddly though, the corresponding function definition itself has no such problem; Sonar doesn't complain about this.

Any thoughts as to why, and how I might get around it?

Comment: you can add an ignore rule as a last resort

Comment: @adnankamili Which I may well resort to. Is there a way to ignore a particular line in c++ Sonar?

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing if you're compiling C or C++ code. In the latter case, I suggest to use the `ctime.h` header and then use `std::tm`. Maybe that will do the trick for the analysis.
If you still need to resort to sonar-ignoring the lines, you can use

```
time_t MyFunction (tm* time); // NOSONAR
```

AFAIK this works without further configuration. We're using

```
//sonarqube ingore on
time_t MyFunction (tm* time);
//sonarqube ingore off
```

to ignore code blocks. This however might need a sonarqube configuration to make the flag known. We're using the following in a pom.xml, and it might be different but similar in your environment:

```
<sonar.issue.ignore.block>e1</sonar.issue.ignore.block>
<sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.beginBlockRegexp>sonarqube ignore on</sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.beginBlockRegexp>
<sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.endBlockRegexp>sonarqube ignore off</sonar.issue.ignore.block.e1.endBlockRegexp>
```

Unfortunately, SQ documentation focuses more on how to handle rules and their exceptions in the project configuration rather than in code, so this information isn't so easy to find..

Regarding your other question: In my experience, SQ will complain about a code smell like yours at the declaration only, so you won't get the same warning in your c/cpp file.